# Expose host port for specific container interface

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a container with more than one network interface. I want to expose a port on only *one* of those interfaces to the host machine. Can this be done?

For example:

```
services:
  foo:
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    networks:
      - one
      - two
      - three

networks:
  one:
    driver: bridge
  two:
    driver: bridge
  three:
    driver: bridge
```

I want it so that port 5000 on the host is mapped to the interface for the network called `two` for example. However, neither the `one` nor `three` interfaces should be reachable from the host through this mapping. Possible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, maybe I'm completely wrong or outdated, or both, but I think you are mixing things here.

the "ports" part allows you to expose the ports from your container to your physical machine, not your "docker networks".

The networks "one, two, three" are all docker networks, so all your ports are exposed without mapping.

Comment: I'm talking about exposing ports from the container to the host, not from the container to the networks. The caveat is that I'm interested only in exposing a port for only one of the container interfaces; not all three of them.

Comment: You can by specifying the ip address, not the interface name. For example: `192.168.1.7:5000:5000`

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, that specifies and ip for one of the hosts interfaces. So the host will forward requests to that ip on that port into the container. What I'd like is for the host to forward requests to a specific network interface within the container.

Comment: Ok so that's what I understood first. And I think that you can't, the port mapping works only between your container and your host, if you connect your container to specific networks, everything is directly exposed